# Two Weapon Fighting Feat with light weapons

Tags: pathfinder-1e, combat, feats, weapons

Hello I am relatively new to pathfinder and I have read that when using the two weapons the penalties are as followed.

Normal penalties –6/-10, Off-hand weapon is light –4/–8, Two-Weapon Fighting feat –4/–4, Two-Weapon Fighting feat w/ Off-hand weapon is light –2/–2,

I was however informed that if you are using two light weapons(ie. short swords), the feat won't apply. I haven't been able to read anywhere that supports that statement, since the feat description never mentions what the main hand needs to be and neither does the two weapon section of combat. Is there a section that mentions this restriction or was a misinformed?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In short, you are right and misinformed. The general rule is, when the situation fits the rule, and there is nothing *in another rule* to counter that, then you interpret the situation as in that rule.

In your case, when your off-hand weapon is light, -2/-2 is applied with TWF, and -4/-8 without it. Nowhere in the rule calls for the kind of weapon in the main hand, so you apply -2/-2 or -4/-8 (without the feat) no matter you are wielding a short sword or a longsword in the main hand.

Answer (score 7):

- Using the Two-Weapon Fighting combat option to get an extra attack with a second weapon? Check.
- Offhand one is light? Check.

Sounds like −2/−2 to me! Those are the only conditions the feat places on the reduced penalty, and you meet both, so it applies.

The rules aren’t perfect or anything, but they do usually *try* to be fairly self-contained. If you can’t find a requirement or condition in a feat itself, *there probably isn’t one.*